# Remove duplicates in a linked list in java

Tags: java, list, nodes

I try to remove duplicates in a simple list with the following code:

```
public void eliminarRepetidos(){
    if(this.isEmpty())
        return;

    for(Nodo<T> n = this.cab; n!=null; n=n.getSiguiente()){
        for(Nodo<T> m = n.getSiguiente(); m!=null; m=m.getSiguiente()){
            if(n.getInfo() == m.getInfo()){
                eliminar(m);
            }
        }
    }
}


private void eliminar(Nodo<T> m){
    Nodo<T> aux =this.cab;
    while(aux.getSiguiente()!= m){
        aux = aux.getSiguiente();
    }
    aux.setSiguiente(m.getSiguiente());
    m.setSiguiente(null);
    this.tam--;
}
```

If the list is empty nothing will be executed.if (isEmpty ())
If the list has elements then I proceed to delete taking as a reference the head node which in this case would be node n that is in the first for.
node m will always be positioned ahead of node n (Second for), m will iterate looking for matches and if it finds any, it will eliminate said node (m), that is, eliminate (m) ;.

When entering the delete method (Node m) what I do is create an auxiliary node (Aux node) and this will iterate until it is the previous one to the node m passed by parameter, this in order not to lose the continuity of the list.

At the time of testing, I enter the Integer data list: 1-> 1-> 1-> 1-> 1-> 1-> 1-> 1-> 1-> 1-> null

You should give me an answer 1-> null.

But it doesn't delete them all, the output is as follows: 1-> 1-> 1-> 1-> 1-> null

I have tried for a while and cannot eliminate them all, what am I failing? Or what do I have to correct for the code to work?

Comment: I would highly recommend attaching a debugger to your code and going through it line by line, observing how every line of code modifies the list. That'll help you quickly zero in on the issue and will hopefully be a great learning experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are doing

```
eliminar(m);
```

and the for at the end of the iteration is doing

```
m.getSiguiente();
```

which will return `null` because inside `eliminar` you have set the `siguente` to null... instead you should do this inside the second loop:

```
Nodo<T> tmp = m.getSiguiente();
eliminar(m);
m = tmp;
```

Comment: @JohnnyAlexanderQuinteroReye please mark the answer as correct and consider leaving an upvote, thank you